# How to handle multiple application in CI/CD pipeline of bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I have more than 15 application ( web application + console application ) to be build and deplyoed in various environments ( Dev, Qa and prod) via tool bamboo.

What will be the correct approach 
1. Create separate project for each application
2. Create 1 project and put all the application under it ( plans, stages ).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have only applications related to one project/product, it's good to group applications in project for (at least) two reasons:

- bamboo provides reporting (i.e. wallboard) across all plans in the project
- when you create application that is not related to your project/product it will be separated

See chatper *How is a Bamboo workflow organized* [on this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo0603/understanding-the-bamboo-ci-server-938868289.html)